# (Python 2.7.5) How to use a python module without installing it

Tags: python-2.7

My problem is as follows:

I'm working on a plugin for the QGIS desktop application at the moment. In my python code I use the enum34 as well as the pyproj modules. For the phase of implemention I installed the modules in my Python environment.

For testing the functionality I set up a VM based on the target environment of the plugin. As far as I know, there will be no possibility to install modules in the future environment of the plugin. The python environment which is installed within the installtion of QGIS doesn't include the necessary modules.

I already read about appending it to sys.path but it won't work...

So, how can I import a module without installing it, respectively is it essential to build the .egg so it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can do:
try:
    import elevation
except:
    pip.main(['install', '--target=%s' % self.elevation_dir, 'elevation'])
    if self.elevation_dir not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(self.elevation_dir)

But normaly, this is an installation issue!
Those issues are not subject of the source code...

The pythonic way is defining your dependencies properly inside the setup.py of your package using the `install_requires` configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your advise.
I already solved my problem by adding the path to the sys.path.
I tried this way but it didn't work. After starting from scratch it works now.
In case anyone else has the same problem here is my "solution":

from os.path import expanduser

home = expanduser("~")

enum_path = home + '\.qgis2\python\plugins\CoordinatesConverter\lib\enum34-1.1.6-py2.7.egg'


import sys

sys.path.insert(0,enum_path)

import enum